# Using AJAX to call a Rails controller method that takes a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I know there are lots of other questions that address calling rails controller methods using AJAX, but I don't see any that call a rails controller method that requires a parameter, in my case, "def sum_graph(date)"

I am using the Chart.js bar graph and I get the values of the bars using this rails method.  Upon updating the values that are used by the sum_graph(date) method via best_in_place, I would like to be able to call that method using the new values to update the chart without refreshing the page.

My code so far looks like this (I'm only updating one bar in the graph since I'm just trying to get it to work):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.best_in_place').bind("ajax:success", function() {
        myBar.datasets[0].bars[0].value = <%= sum_graph(Date.current - 24.months) %>;
        myBar.update();
    });
});
```

If I replace the sum_graph(date) method in this code with a random number generator, it indeed updates the bar with the random value every time I change a value using best_in_place so I think I'm headed in the right direction.  So is my code indeed re-calling this method each time I change a value, just without the new values?  Either way, any help here to resolve this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Your `<%= sum_graph(Date.current - 24.months) %>;` function is called when the js.erb file is rendered, not when the ajax success callback is fired. You would either need to do another ajax call to get the server to process the data or do the same function in javascript.

Comment: Hey max, thanks for the quick response.  What would the ajax call to get the server to process the data look like (roughly) and where would I put it?  I'm really new to this so I appreciate your patience.

Comment: I don't know. I have no idea what your function even does.